# ejabberd chunked file streaming mode

Tags: android, ejabberd

In Android (specifically java.net.HttpURLConnection class) there is a setChunkedStreamingMode(int chunkLength) function, which sets chunked mode for file transfer. But how to enable that option on the ejabberd server?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this feature is not supported in ejabberd.